# How to debounce a callback in functional component using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I get actual prop values in React Functional Component debounced callbacks, It worked in React Class Component, but I have no idea how to reach this behavior in functional component using hooks.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

const TestFunc = ({ count, onClick }) => {
  const handleClick = debounce(() => {
    onClick();
    console.log(count);
  }, 500);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Func: {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

class TestClass extends React.Component {
  handleClick = debounce(() => {
    this.props.onClick();
    console.log(this.props.count);
  }, 500);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Class: {this.props.count}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [countClass, setCountClass] = React.useState(0);
  const [countFunc, setCountFunc] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <TestFunc count={countFunc} onClick={() => setCountFunc(countFunc + 1)} />
      <TestClass
        count={countClass}
        onClick={() => setCountClass(countClass + 1)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When you click on functional component button, it logs the previous `count` prop value to console, but it's already changed by calling `onClick` handler, in the same time the class component button would log the actual `count` prop value after it was incremented by `onClick` handler. So, how can I get actual prop values in functional component?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a simple debounce hook (written in TypeScript)

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function useDebouncedCallback<A extends any[]>(
  callback: (...args: A) => void,
  wait: number
) {
  // track args & timeout handle between calls
  const argsRef = useRef<A>();
  const timeout = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>();

  function cleanup() {
    if(timeout.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }
  }

  // make sure our timeout gets cleared if
  // our consuming component gets unmounted
  useEffect(() => cleanup, []);

  return function debouncedCallback(
    ...args: A
  ) {
    // capture latest args
    argsRef.current = args;

    // clear debounce timer
    cleanup();

    // start waiting again
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      if(argsRef.current) {
        callback(...argsRef.current);
      }
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Example for your use case:

```
const handleClick = useDebouncedCallback(() => {
  onClick();
  console.log(count);
}, 500);

... 

<button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
  Func: {count}
</button>
```

Also works for cases that pass arguments:

```
const handleChange = useDebouncedCallback((event) => {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
}, 500);

<input onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Comment: You should use useCallback in order to store debouncedCallback result.

Comment: @Naor how you mean?

Comment: You should useCallback like this: `function useDebouncedCallback(cb, w, deps?: DependecnyList) { return useCallback(function debouncedCallback() { ... }, deps);`

Comment: not sure if it's any different but can replace `A extends any[]` with T and then where array is expected write T[] instead. stylistically seems like a more natural generic that way to me

Comment: @ColinD that isn’t the same thing. That would mean all args have to be the same type. As-is it will support multiple args of different types

Comment: thanks for clarifying, i wasn't thinking too deeply about that

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a few changes to use `debounced method` with hook

1. You need to make use of the `useCallback` hook so that the debounced function is only created once on the initial render.
2. Now if you have to make sure that debounced gets the correct count value when its executed, you need to pass it as a param else it will use the value from its enclosing closure at the time of its creation which is the initial count value.
3. You need to update the count value on onClick method call using the callback pattern in parent like `setCountFunc(count => count + 1)` so that the child components re-render with the updated value

Working demo below

```js
const TestFunc = ({ count, onClick }) => {
  const handleClick = React.useCallback(_.debounce((count) => {
          onClick();
          console.log(count);
     }, 500), []);

  console.log(count, 'render');
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick(count)}>
        Func: {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

class TestClass extends React.Component {
  handleClick = _.debounce(() => {
    this.props.onClick();
    console.log(this.props.count);
  }, 500);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Class: {this.props.count}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [countClass, setCountClass] = React.useState(0);
  const [countFunc, setCountFunc] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <TestFunc count={countFunc} onClick={() => setCountFunc(count => count + 1)} />
      <TestClass
        count={countClass}
        onClick={() => setCountClass(countClass + 1)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 3):

for debounce API call in functional components

```
<input
 type="text"
 placeholder="Search"
 onChange={(e) => search(e.target.value)}
/>
=========================================================================
  const [typingTimeout, setTypingTimeout] = useState(0);
const search = async (value) => {
    if (typingTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
    }
    setTypingTimeout( setTimeout(() => {
        goToSearch(value);
      }, 1000)
    );

  }
  const goToSearch = async (value) => {
    const response = await getData(args);
  }
```

for class components
same as above but change in search function

```
const search = (event.target.value) =>{
    if (this.state.typingTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.state.typingTimeout);
    }
    this.setState({
      typingTimeout: setTimeout(()=> {
        this.goToSearch(event.target.value);
      }, 1000)
    });
}
```

for typeScript

```
setTypingTimeout( window.setTimeout(() => {
          goToSearch(value);
        }, 1000)
      );
```

use `window.setTimeout`